# 16 general purpose CPUs in today's world

Tags: mobile, architecture, cpu, 16-bit

What is the reason for replacing 16-bit processors with 32-bit, and then 64-bit?
Is it possible with modern technical processes and the presence of various SIMD extensions to create a full-fledged device with a 16-bit architecture of the main arithmetic-logical device that can compete with modern counterparts (provided that all software and operating systems are written purposefully) in the media / mobile sphere? Are there any modern general purpose 16-bit processors out there today?

Comment: Yes, 16-bit CPUs have use in embedded systems. Sometimes, power efficiency is more important than performance. There are even 8-bit CPUs still in use! But not for general-purpose computing.

Comment: This is the answer to some other question.
I'm interested in the reason for the transition from 16 to 32 bit architectures (this is the main question).